# How to make an never ending UITableView?

Tags: iphone, tableview

I have some options in an UITableView and want that the user can scroll forever. When the end is reached, I want to append the begginning so the user can continue to scroll.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return some huge number, and act accordingly in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` by returning same cells over and over.

You can also have limited number of rows, and at the end show a different cell - containing a button for user which he can use to append new rows. When that button is clicked you simply call `[tableView reloadData]` and provide more rows in table's data source.

Aren't you by any chance misusing the table-view for something it doesn't fit that well ? Maybe you would be better off using just a UIScrollView and reposition subviews as user scrolls over.

Comment: you're totally right. Table view is overkill in my case... there are like 20 items only.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only problem is how to trick in the method `numberOfRows:`. One possible solution is to return some big number here, for example, `10 000`. Then, you set up a correct `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to return based on your data's number modulo. For example, if you have 100 data entity, then you have to get the indexPath.row % 100